# MySQL get subquery value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to calculate the distance of my centroid point, that's calculated through the total number of tags, and sum of the instant time that tags appear. So that's the concept of (tc_sum/cnt).
However the SELECT on the subquery, doesn't allow me to get the centroid point, because the "centr" is not calculated yet, and so i can't get the "distance".
Any help?

```
SELECT cnt, tc_sum, ROUND(tc_sum/cnt) as centr, distance
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(timecode) as tc_sum, count(timecode) as cnt, ABS( centr - '".$timecode."' ) AS distance
    FROM dados d
    WHERE tag = 'donald'
    AND filename = 'donald.mp4'
    AND group_id = '1'
    ) d
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'centr' in 'field list'

Comment: you cant use centr like this. try copying "ROUND(tc_sum/cnt)" in the 2nd query instead of "centr"

Comment: @AshReva if i do that i get the same error, because tc_sum is not calculated yet...

Comment: You cannot access fields defined in a super-query from a subquery because the super-query result only exists afterwards, *based on* the subquery. [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way: Describe the goal, not the step](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal)

Comment: @PointedEars You're right! Next time i explained it in "The smart Way" ;)

Comment: You can still edit your question.

Comment: @PointedEars Better?! :)

Comment: No, there are still too many unknowns, like what data are you processing and what query result you are expecting. You should read the guide I referred to from the top, then, and the FAQ, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 SUM(timecode) as tc_sum, 
 SUM(timecode) as cnt, 
 ABS( SUM(timecode) / SUM(timecode) - '".$timecode."' ) AS distance, 
 ROUND(SUM(timecode) / SUM(timecode)) AS centr
FROM dados d
WHERE tag = 'donald'
 AND filename = 'donald.mp4'
 AND group_id = '1'
```

A query works on row after row and you can't refer to aliases this way. You have to "recalculate" them again. "Recalculate" is not the right word, since the result isn't really calculated multiple times. The optimizer will take care of it being only calculated once. But an alias is only known after the query ran. I'm afraid my english sucks too much to explain it in a good way :)

Comment: In part, it works, but i lost the concept of the calculation of the centroid point!

Comment: @zppinto what do you mean by it?

Comment: @zppinto Yes, what do you mean?

Comment: I already edited the code! Now it works as I pretend! :)  
Thank you both for your help!

Comment: @zppinto You mean "now" it works? Typo? Accept the answer that helped you, please.

Comment: Yes, I mean "now". I already edited it and accepted the answers. You can accept my edit if you want to.

Comment: @zppinto I don't see any edit. Doesn't matter, I guess. :) Have a nice day, glad I could help.

Comment: @tombom Yeah, it doesn't matter! In your code i just edit the "/ SUM(timecode)" to "/COUNT(timecode)", and it's working as expected! :) 
Have a nice day too! And thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT cnt, tc_sum, ROUND(tc_sum/cnt) as centr, distance
FROM (
SELECT SUM(timecode) as tc_sum, count(timecode) as cnt, ABS( ROUND(tc_sum/cnt)- '".$timecode."' ) AS  distance
FROM dados d
WHERE tag = 'donald'
AND filename = 'donald.mp4'
AND group_id = '1'
) d
```